# how to fix tf.constant unexpected argument error

Tags: tensorflow, resnet

In the original code flags were set like tf.apps.flags.DEFINE_string(
    'master', '', 'The address of the TensorFlow master to use.'). then i changed the tf.app.flags to tf.flags

originally FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS, changed to tf.flags.FLAGS similarly.

but the error in the tf.constant has been there in both the cases. how to fix it?
i feel like this error has something to do with the python versions. but cant figure it out

replica_id=tf.constant(FLAGS.task, dtype=tf.int32, shape=()),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for me it works just fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer('task', 10, "my value for the constant")

# now define your constant
replica_id = tf.constant(value=FLAGS.task, dtype=tf.float32)

# see if it works:
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(replica_id))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. your code works on mine when i run it on its own. but changing to value = FLAGS.task doesn't work for mine. i think maybe the error is not coming from that function. its used inside another function.

Comment: optimizer = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(
          opt=optimizer,
          replicas_to_aggregate=FLAGS.replicas_to_aggregate,
          variable_averages=variable_averages,
          variables_to_average=moving_average_variables,
          replica_id=tf.constant(value=FLAGS.task, dtype=tf.int32),
          total_num_replicas=FLAGS.worker_replicas)

Comment: can you share a couple of additional lines of code to better understand the workflow, please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QlgRNTsrg152qSyFFSkWBLZlpfRr3flH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: which Tensorflow version are you using? because in 1.12.0 the tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer() has no replica_id argument defined

Comment: it is 1.12.  so how can i fix this. in line 581 it FLAGS.sinc_repilcas is used again, so how to call that function properly.